# no ALSA modules loaded

Tags: sound, alsa

I've been trying to get the soundblaster audigy SE to work: I've managed to tell the kernel it's there. but because the alsa-project.org Matrix:Vendor-Creative_Labs tells me to load the 'old' oss modules, that's what I (finally, after loooooots of troubleshooting), doing that just completely messed up alsa (or maybe all the sound settings?): http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=10e8d476b8147475829b20ee7008bbd4136fa96c

Very frustrating, I have no more sound at all. **How can I get alsamixer and all the modules back?** (at least onboard audio was working, now all sound cards are "unclaimed"):

```
$ sudo lshw |grep multimedia
        *-multimedia:0 UNCLAIMED
           *-multimedia UNCLAIMED
        *-multimedia:1 UNCLAIMED
           *-multimedia UNCLAIMED
```

IN case it's of any help, I have found that

```
$ modprobe -c |grep sound
blacklist sound
blacklist dmasound_core
blacklist dmasound_pmac
blacklist soundcard
blacklist snd_aoa_soundbus
blacklist sound
blacklist dmasound_core
blacklist dmasound_pmac
blacklist soundcard
```

btw, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure told me to come here. 
Seems like I need your help.
thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Because of setting up OSS, I had some oss*.conf files in /etc/modprobe that blacklisted 'everything' (especially there was one called _noALSA)

I simply deleted these (in effect unblacklisting 'everything', I guess) and yes, onboard sound is back. My soundcard still isn't working but that's a different topic:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36756123/sound-blaster-audigy-se-ubuntu-no-output
so this discussion may be closed.

Comment: The information in the wiki is likely to be wrong. Anyway, where do all those blacklist entries come from? Did you put something in some configuration file in `/etc/modprobe.d/`? Did you try to install OSS from 4front-tech.com?